# cheat sheet for putting up a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a cheat sheet for putting up a Rails app (scaffolding is OK) all I need is 1 database called users with 2 fields name and email as string fields. I need the commands from:

```
rails new app_name
```

to:

```
localhost:3000/users
```

Comment: There are numerous rails tutorials on the internet. Have you tried them?

Comment: what I'm looking for is a list of commands. A lot of the videos start slow but fly by some of the actual things that they are typing.

Answer (score 3):

A quick googling of `rails cheat sheet` gave me this, which looks quite good: http://blog.envylabs.com/post/29044764623/rails-3-cheat-sheets

To get from `rails new app_name` to `localhost:3000` I think the commands would be something like this (when scaffolding):

```
rails new app_name
cd app_name
rails generate scaffold user name:string email:string
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

By the way, try running just a command without parameters to read the documentation and usage examples, e.g. `rails` or `rails generate` or `rails generate scaffold` inside the **app_name** directory

Answer (score 0):

A resource that I found after I was familiar with the Rails framework is [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). The online book is free and from what I've read seems to cover all the bases. Because it is a book you can follow at your own pace, but he does offer screencasts if that's your thing.

Another website that has tutorials is [PeepCode](https://peepcode.com/). They have two screencasts on learning Rails 3.

1. [Meet Rails 3 (part 1)](https://peepcode.com/products/meet-rails-3-i)
2. [Meet Rails 3 (part 2)](https://peepcode.com/products/meet-rails-3-ii)

I have never followed those two tutorials in particular, but I did purchase their two tutorials back around 2007 titled [Rails from Scratch](https://peepcode.com/products/rails-from-scratch-part-i). However, don't purchase these because the Rails framework has changed a ton since then.

---

I know I didn't give you a list of commands, but part of learning the Rails commands is learning the framework itself. Here is the guide for the [Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).